# How to append content in li into form inout value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say i have a div with list and a `form input`

```
<ul>
    <li>What is my name</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="" id="form">
```

I want such that when i click on the `li` tag, the content 'What is my name' of the `li` is tranfered to the `input value`  with `JavaScript`

Below is what i have tried.

```
$('li').click(function(){
  $('#from').val() = $('li').innerHTML();
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Please what is the way out?

Comment: That's jQuery and it has to be $('#from').val($(this).html())

Comment: _“Please what is the way out?”_ - that you simply go read the documentation to find out how it actually works? http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: You've an another question. What's about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul><li>What is my name</li></ul>

<input type="text" value="" id="form">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li').click(function() {
    $('#form').val($('li').text());
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the value to `val` *constructor*.

```
$('#from').val($(this).text());
```

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  $('#form').val($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>What is my name</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="" id="form">
```

Comment: `val` is not a constructor. It's just a function (loosely speaking, a method). Probably worth mentioning the typo, too.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `li`s text to the `val()` function as a parameter:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('#form').val($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>What is my name</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="" id="form">
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not using the `val()` method the right way. It must be used like that:

```
$('#from').val($('li').innerHTML());
```

Anyway… The answer you accepted won't work if you have multiple `li`.

You must want to use the `this` keyword to get the content of the `li` you clicked.

Here is a snippet to explain that:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('#form1').val($('li').text()); // Not correct, in my opinion
});

$('li').click(function() {
  $('#form2').val($(this).text()); // Correct, in my opinion!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Name 1</li>
  <li>Name 2</li>
  <li>Name 3</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="" id="form1">
<span>With $('li'), it takes the value of all the list-items</span>
<br>
<input type="text" value="" id="form2">
<span>With $(this), it takes only the value of the list-item you clicked</span>
```

Documentation about `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$('li').click(function(){
$('#form').val($('li')[0].innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: this won't add the clicked `li`s text into ipnut.
This will always add the first `li`s text. `HTML` to be more precise